# [RAILS]: cloudinary display photo1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, helper, cloudinary

Hi there I m new on Ror, 
On my new app, I use cloudinary and attachinary gem to display my photos on my product page.
I don't succeed to display only the first photo corresponding to my product instead of all my product photos, on my show page.
Is there any cloudinary helper to say I want product.picture 1 or product.picture 2 to be displayed at this place?
Thks for your help,

Here is my code:
lesson.html.erb

```
   <% @lesson.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= cl_image_tag photo.path, width: 400, height: 200, crop: :fill %>
   <% end %>
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   Photo 1  <%= f.input :photo %>
   <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %><br>
   Photo 2  <%= f.input :photo %>
   <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %><br>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: what you are using for uploading photos ? paperclip or carrierwave ?

Comment: I use carrierwave

Comment: Did you try: `<%= image_tag photo_url, width: 400, height: 200, crop: :fill %>` since that's the way of displaying an image when using carrierwave

Comment: That is not working as well :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you just want to just display the particular photo from the @lessons.photos array

```
 <% image_tag @lesson.photos.first.photo_url %>
```

or second you do

```
 <% image_tag @lesson.photos.second.photo_url %>
```

and so on!! Is this what you are asking?

OR if your code is working for you then:

```
 <%= cl_image_tag @lesson.photos.first.path, width: 400, height: 200, crop: :fill %>
```

or you can do

```
@lesson.photos[0] for first and @lesson.photos[1] for second photo & so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

please try url instead of path

```
   <%= cl_image_tag photo.url, width: 400, height: 200, crop: :fill %>
```

Let me know if its not work